# How Do I Simplify $1 - \frac{1}{2^{m-1}} + \frac{1}{2^{m}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Someone help.  Somehow my textbook says that it simplifies to $1 - \frac{2}{2^{m}} + \frac{1}{2^{m}}$  I don't see this at all.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2^{m-1}} = \frac{1\cdot 2}{2^{m-1}\cdot 2} = \frac{2}{2^m}$

Comment: curious if you are the one second from left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: use the property of exponents: $2^{m-1} = \dfrac{2^m}{2}$, and note that: $\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{2^m}{2}} = \dfrac{2}{2^m}$

Answer (score 1):

They have just multiplied the second term by 1 but in a special way:

$$
\begin{split} &1-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}+\frac{1}{2^m} \\ =&1-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\cdot \frac{2}{2}+\frac{1}{2^m} \\=&1-\frac{2}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^m}  \end{split}
$$

Comment: thank you for answering first.

Answer (score 0):

$$1 - (\frac{1}{2})^{m-1} + (\frac{1}{2})^{m}$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 - \frac{1^{m-1}}{2^{m-1}} + \frac{1^{m}}{2^{m}}$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 - \frac{1}{2^{m-1}} + \frac{1}{2^{m}}$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 - \frac{1\cdot2}{2^{m-1}2} + \frac{1}{2^{m}}$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 - \frac{2}{2^{m}} + \frac{1}{2^{m}}$$

Answer (score 0):

One property of exponents is that $x^{m + n} = x^{m}x^{n}$, and another one is $x^{-m} = \frac{1}{x^{m}}$. In your case, it's the second term which has been simplified, the rest is unchanged. $\frac{1}{2^{m-1}} = \frac{1}{2^{m}2^{-1}}$. Using the second property I stated in reverse will give you $\frac{1}{2^{m}2^{-1}} = \frac{2^{1}}{2^{m}} = \frac{2}{2^{m}}$. I hope this helped.

Comment: This is how I was beginning to think about it, but I didn't think about far enough.  Thank you for pointing this out to me.